# How to register button being clicked in Google Analytic?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

i have a slider where I also have two button prev and next. These can be clicked to make the slider go prev and next items. However, in Google Analytics, I do not seem to get them registered at all.

The html code I have is

```
<span class="direction"><button id="prevButton">Prev</button></span>
```

And, the javascript I have to register is as below

```
    /* Tracks all a href links */
    $('a').click(function(e){
        ga('send','event','Link (Open Day)', 'Click (Open Day)',$(this).text().trim());
    })
```

Comment: Your click listener is listening in on a nonexistent anchor element.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try :

```js
/* Tracks all a href links */
$('.direction button').click(function(e){
    ga('send','event','Link (Open Day)', 'Click (Open Day)',$(this).html().trim());
})
```

*$('a').click()* detects clicks on HTML links. You want to detect clicks on your button instead.

See [the JQuery API doc](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) or [this page on W3 School](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp) for more details.

Also, if your slider (and buttons) are added dynamically, you should use [JQuery's on() method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) on an existing object.